# Change local path of referenced project

Tags: c#, csproj

I'm building a set of plugin assemblies that I want to load in my main application. For that reason I have to search through a plugin directory named "plugins". I currently have my plugins attached to my main applications' solution with all projects in my solution and all projects are added as ProjectReference in the project file of the main application with CopyLocal set to true.

The problem is the I want to have the project reference outputs not copied to the OutputPath of the main application, but in a subfolder. I couldn't find any option to set something like this.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly this is what you want.

In the plugins project right click -> properties -> build -> output path

You can change the output path to anywhere you need and have the parent project reference the assemblies in that folder.

[image]

Comment: Yes, you are almost right, excedpt that we have a configuration file and the Output Path is not able to use variables. Nevertheless we have changed now our config file -  at least for the plugin and it seems to work that way. Thanks for your help.